# Error inflating class include in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.emphie.fod/org.emphie.fod.preferences}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class include

I'm trying to include a switch preference in versions that support it, otherwise a check box preference. It's fair to say I haven't been able to find any docco whatsoever on includes, but the *examples* I have seen are all for layouts, not preferences.

It seems crazy to require all preference fragments to wholly defined for their appropriate API when only some elements require different definitions.

Screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enabled="true" android:fragment="org.emphie.fod.preferences$prefFrag1" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Preferences" >
        <include android:key = "@+id/send_sms" xml="@xml/pref_send_sms" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Included preferences:
In res-v14:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:disableDependentsState="false"
        android:key="@+id/send_SMS"
        android:summaryOff="Just generate insults"
        android:summaryOn="Actually send the wanker insults"
        android:switchTextOff="No"
        android:switchTextOn="Yes"
        android:title="Send SMS" />
</merge>
```

and in res-v8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:disableDependentsState="false"
        android:key="@+id/send_SMS"
        android:summaryOff="Just generate insults"
        android:summaryOn="Actually send the wanker insults"
        android:switchTextOff="No"
        android:switchTextOn="Yes"
        android:title="Send SMS" />
</merge>
```

Links to appropriate docco gratefully received, along with google-fu tips. Am I doing something fundamentally, syntactically or stupidly wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, after much research it turns out this is utterly unreasonable and impossible.

Comment: Don't leave us hanging, say a little more about how you figured that out. :)

Comment: Sorry; I was ranting. I couldn't find a single reference to doing this anywhere on the web, so I just gave up. I'm happy to be corrected though.

Comment: Yep utterly unreasonably and impossible. Still it's very nice of the chaps at google to create 'utility' classes like PreferenceActivity to simplfy the creation of boilerplate settings code... except where you have to actually recode everything for the gingerbread users who despite all the fervent wishes in Mountain View are just not spontaneously combusting at a statistically significant rate. Nice job guys.